# Block creation in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1, layout, template, blocks

Well I have created a block in my XML file with a **type** as one of my PHP class file and I also gave the **template**, **name** and as **parameters**, but unfortunately I am unable to get that block on my page. I have called that block from my PHTML file using getChildHtml('Name_Of_The_Block'); But it seems there is some problem in my code. Can I know what may be the possible reasons for this error?

Comment: more info please. Layout_XML, Block class, phtml.

Comment: check permission of files/pages..

Comment: Where should i check the permissions?

Comment: Did you refresh the cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some reference links to create magento block.

[1. creating custom template block in magento](http://aaronbonner.io/post/606455710/creating-a-custom-template-block-in-magento)

[2. custom-reference-structural-block](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/custom-reference-structural-block/)